# How can I reuse text that is used as an xml attribute?

Tags: xml

So I have an xml file similar to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE universal-layout [
<!ENTITY formNames "basic-component, universal-component, another-form, cool-form, really-cool-form">,
<!ENTITY displayNames "Basic Component, Universal Component, Another Form, Cool Form, Really Cool Form">
]>
<my-component-form-1 form-names="&formNames;" form-display-names="&formDisplayNames;">
    <some-other-element/>
</my-component-form-1>

<my-component-form-2 form-names="&formNames;" form-display-names="&formDisplayNames;">
    <some-other-element/>
</my-component-form-2>

<my-component-form-3 form-names="&formNames;" form-display-names="&formDisplayNames;">
    <some-other-element/>
</my-component-form-3>
```

Basically I'm just substituting the formNames and displayNames entities throughout the xml so I don't have to have duplicated code.

However, I need these two entities in other xml files as well and I don't want to just copy and paste the entities because I want to be able to update them in just one place.

Is there a way I can include them in a separate xml file as a reference of some sort? I hope there is an example of how to do it somewhere. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XInclude

It looks like there are a few things out there that will behave similarly, but I am not sure if this is what you are looking for?